# Power BI native maps can't handle large data

Tags: powerbi, maps, large-data

I need to show millions of points on Power BI native maps. I read that the basic one has a limit of 3,500 points and Azure maps has 30,000. Python maps have about 1,500 points limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-data-points

I have a slicer for the data and when I zoom somewhere and change the slicer some points disappear.

What is the best way to show millions of points in a map in Power BI considering performance and data privacy?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, custom visuals can go up to 30k data points, while R and Python can go up to 150k, nothing higher than that sadly. The user should be free to choose the compromise between performance and data visualization

Comment: Microsoft support suggested that I use ArcGIS third party maps alternative to show higher than 150k of data points.